# Publication statistics per research company

Tags: industry, reference-request, bibliometrics

Is there any website or other places that give some publication statistics (e.g. number of published papers, number of citations, etc.) per company? Ideally I would like to have those statistics computed for some time period, e.g. for every year.

Note that I am talking about industrial research organizations here, not publishing companies.

Comment: you can use scopus or isi web of science and in affiliation, write the name of the company. that easy

Comment: For those voting to close, please tell me what is unclear...

Comment: @flow Can you please expand slightly into an answer, so I can vote it up?

Answer (score 3):

To find the number of citations to people at a company, you can use [Scopus](http://www.scopus.com/search/form.url?zone=TopNavBar&origin=AffiliationNamesList) or [Thomson Reuters Web of Science](http://apps.webofknowledge.com/UA_GeneralSearch_input.do?product=UA&search_mode=GeneralSearch) (formerly ISI Web of Knowledge) and, in the affiliation field, write the name of the company.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you please add a screenshot for Thomson Reuters Web of Science looking for articles by authors from Microsoft?